# in firebase ,when i use useCollectionData hook( firebase ) , i cannot manage orderBy property.How to fix that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import { collection, deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../../firebase_2";
const query = collection(db, `default_data/${categoryName}/children`);
const [docs, loading, error] = useCollectionData(query);
{changeWordList &&
          docs?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div
                  onClick={(event) =>
                    handleClickChangeEverything(
                      item.turkishWord,
                      item.englishWord,
                      event
                    )
                  }
                  className={styles.container_single_card}
                  key={index}
                >
                  <div className={styles.word_part}>{item.englishWord}</div>

                  <button
                    className={styles.delete_button}
                    onClick={() => handleDeleteSubCollection(item.uuid)}
                  >
                    <GoTrash />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

in firebase ,when i use useCollectionData hook( firebase ) , i cannot manage orderBy property. I want to order the data alphabetically.How i can do?
i do  not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import { collection, query, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../../firebase_2";

const q = query(
  collection(db, `default_data/${categoryName}/children`),
  orderBy("englishWord") // Replace "englishWord" with the field you want to order by
);

const [docs, loading, error] = useCollectionData(q);
```

Comment: i got the error =>Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_internalPath')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_internalPath') @Kareem Adel

Comment: can you provide more details ( i edited the answer in anyway)